# Unexpected behavior of printf()

Tags: c, gcc

I executed following code in ubuntu with gcc compiler.

As `a=0`, the second `printf()` prints some garbage value.

What kind of behavior is it by `printf()`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 0;

    printf("\nThe Value of %ns : %d\n", &a, a);
    printf("\n%d\n", a);

    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please post the output you are getting

Comment: why do you think it's garbage? Did you read the printf manual page?

Comment: Undefined behavior is a technical term. There's no undefined behavior here.

Answer (score 3):

If you read e.g. [this `printf` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) you will see that the `%n` format specifier will:

> returns the **number of characters** written so far by this call to the function.

So it will overwrite the contents of `a` with the number of characters it has written so far, which should be `14` if I count correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The output of the first `printf` is `0`
Because the second argument of `printf` passes `a` by the value and it gets printed afterwards.

The output of the second `printf` is `14`
Because at this time the value of `a` was replaced by the number of characters that was printed before `%n` by the first `printf`

Answer (score 0):

> As a=0, the second printf() prints some garbage value.

You can't believe that statement until you verify it!

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 0;
    printf("\nThe Value of %ns : %d\n", &a, a);
    assert(a == 0);
    printf("\n%d\n", a);
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Any time you want to say "I'm sure that (some invariant) is true at place x", use `assert` to state that fact and let it be checked at runtime.

Output:

```
output.s: ./example.c:8: main: Assertion `a == 0' failed.
```